# Travelling to Dublin via London

Tags: uk

I am travelling to UK from India on a Business Visa.
But have a meeting in Dublin the immediate next day.

I know my BV allows me to travel to Dublin.

My question : My port of entry has  to be London. So do i have to stay overnight in London and travel to Dublin the next day ? or can i land  in London and take a next available flight to Dublin the same day ? 
Will I go through border control and get stamped in london between the 2 flights on the same day? If yes then am good.

Comment: On arrival into Heathrow, you could follow the "UK and Ireland flight connections" flow, which would take you to the UK border before any onward flight to Dublin. Whether or not the UK would admit you on a UK visa with a clear plan to fly to Ireland instead is a different matter, hopefully Gayot Fow will be along shortly to cover that part!

Comment: @Gagravarr He has to do this anyway, the international connections route is not open to Dublin-destined passengers. He will need to go through the biometric capture process you see since other Ireland-destined pax need not have passports.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to Dublin via Heathrow, you will pass through UK Immigration control at Heathrow. You will enter the UK and then continue onto Dublin. Your documents will be inspected again in Dublin.

This is because of the UK's slightly strange travel/passport arrangement with Ireland.

There's no need to stay the night in the UK (unless your visa says so).

Comment: But will UK immigration admit the OP on a UK visa an a plan to go straight to Ireland instead of the UK? Or would they deny the OP on the grounds that a trip to Ireland really ought to be on an Irish visa instead?

Comment: @Pnuts The UK BV issued to Indian nationals now allows short trips to Ireland